# Upgrade iPhone 3GS from iOS 4.2.1 to 4.3.x

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade, ios4, iphone-3gs

Hi folks I have a iPhone 3GS at 4.2.1 and want to upgrade it to 4.3.x for testing. I have read some articles about it but it seems that those are too old and cannot work.

Does anyone have some experience in doing this or does apple provide tutorials for developers in this?

A lot of thanks.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Is this a physical iPhone or the iOS Simulator? If so, then stack overflow may not be the place for this question. Please give more detail on what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Hi @RazorSharp thanks for your comments. I mean the physical phone. I think 3gs in 4.3 should be quite important environment that all apps should support. I have went through some ios upgrade/downgrade questions here but still cannot find a solution. I hope I can find an answer here and also benefit other developers. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 3GS is supported by the current iOS, which is 5.0.1.  You can update to that just by connecting the phone to iTunes and clicking "Update".

You can't update to any other version but the latest.  (Well, not in any officially supported capacity.  It might be possible with jailbreak tools but I don't traffic in those.)

Comment: Thanks @jsd but I'd really like to have a 4.3 iPhone for testing. I don't mind to use jailbreak to upgrade it, if I can get into jail after I got 4.3. (since testflight need a non-jb iphone)

Comment: @ThinkChris Once you jailbreak there's no real way to go back unless you do a restore, and in that case you'd be restoring to the latest version.

Comment: It's ludicrous that Apple doesn't let developers downgrade their devices in order to test for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @ThinkChris The following link tells how to downgrade your device to a certain firmware. Firmware is available here (virus free as far as I know): http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

Comment: @RazorSharp Thank you for your link. have you tried this? i tried it before but it seems that it will connect to apple server for approval and apple obviously say no.

Comment: @ThinkChris I have done this with a jailbroken phone, and it worked. I have never tried the "non-jailbroken" method described in the text on the top of the website though. If you are thinking of jail breaking for this purpose, I believe RedSn0w allows for a custom firmware.